# How to document old value vs new value in generic function callback

Tags: c#, generics, func

I have a generic callback function like this to notify listeners when a value has changed:

```
public Func<T, T, Task> ValueChangedAsync { get; set; }
```

where the first T should be the old value and second T should be the new value.

I will use this callback like this:

```
await ValueChangedAsync(old, newValue);
```

Can I make users of this function aware of which T is the old value and new value?
When using the callback this is what gets implemented by default:

```
private Task ValueChangedAsync(string s, string s1)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

I would really like the "s" to be named "oldValue" and "s1" to be named "newValue" or such.

Comment: Any reason you're using a property rather than an event? You could specify your own delegate type and document things there...

Comment: I would really like to await the callback, you cannot do that with an event?

Comment: Yes you can... although you'd need to think about what you'd do in the face of multiple subscribers.

Comment: OK, I see. Any suggestions or good links on how to implement an awaitable eventhandler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with events and a custom delegate type, where the delegate type documentation can indicate the old value and new value parts. For example:

```
// As we want a non-void return type, we're not following the event conventions
// anyway... so we might as well have three parameters...
public delegate Task ValueChangedHandler<T>(object source, T oldValue, T newValue);
```

Then:

```
public event ValueChangedHandler<string> ValueChanged;
```

Invoke it as:

```
ValueChangedHandler<string> handler = ValueChanged;
if (handler != null)
{
    var allHandlers = handler.GetInvocationList();
    foreach (ValueChangedHandler<string> individualHandler in allHandlers)
    {
        await individualHandler(this, oldValue, newValue);
    }
}
```